# How to view the contents of a Firebird 2.5 database

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I would like to view the contents of a .fdb file and hopefully transfer them to an Excel format, this file is from another computer. I have installed Firebird 2.5 and I have installed FlameRobin

And inside FlameRobin I did Database > Register Existing Database, with username = SYSDBA and password = masterkey

[image]

But I get an error:

"Your login SYSDBA is same as one of the SQL role name. Ask your database Administrator to set up a valid Firebird login"

[image]

I have done enough reading to know that this is supposedly a trick as Firebird 2.5 don't have user. According to this [old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46647723/sysdba-user-is-blocked-from-access-to-firebird-2-x-database). I supposedly have to use IBexpert or IBsurgeon FirstAid, but it is not clear on how to use them. I have downloaded and installed them. I'm supposed to find a table named RDB$ROLES, but I could not find them.

Anyone can help me with a better method?

Comment: Please post error message text as **text**. In any case, I'm not sure what you mean with _"as Firebird 2.5 don't have user"_, Firebird does have users. You need to create a different user (through another database), and then connect with that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel _You need to create a different user (through another database), and then connect with that._ apologies i dont have experience in firebird, i just needed to extract the data in this database. Can you explain to me how to do this? or show me a guide on how to do this? I do not see how creating a new database will give me access to this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This database was "protected" from being accessed by the SYSDBA user by creating a role with the same name.

Be aware that the following steps do come under the assumption that nothing was done to prevent a normal user from selecting from the `RDB$ROLES` table. Otherwise, you will need to use other means to find the right user (e.g. from the application code, tracing the connection), or need a database repair tool to remove/overwrite the role, or inspect the file itself (which does require a lot of knowledge about the internals).

To be able to access it, you will need to create a new user.

#### Creating a new user

In Firebird 2.5, there are basically two ways to create new users:

1. Connect to another database with SYSDBA (or another user with the RDB$ADMIN role). For example, using ISQL, connect to the employee database which is included in standard Firebird installations(*):

   Start ISQL (substitute masterkey with the actual password):

   ```bash
   isql -user sysdba -password masterkey localhost:employee
   ```

   Inside ISQL (substitute thenewuser and thepassword with desired values):

   ```sql
   create user thenewuser password 'thepassword';
   commit;
   exit;
   ```
2. Use GSEC to create a user (note: GSEC has been deprecated in Firebird 3.0):

   Start GSEC (substitute masterkey with the actual password):

   ```bash
   gsec -user sysdba -password masterkey
   ```

   Inside GSEC (substitute thenewuser and thepassword with desired values):

   ```
   add thenewuser -pw thepassword
   ```

This user will not be able to do much, but it should be able to inspect the metadata tables of the database.

#### Find the user needed to drop the role

You should be able to login into to the database (substitute thedatabase with the actual path or alias of the database) with the user created previously:

```bash
isql -user thenewuser -password thepassword localhost:thedatabase
```

Then query who "owns" the role SYSDBA:

```sql
select RDB$OWNER_NAME from RDB$ROLES where RDB$ROLE_NAME = 'SYSDBA';
```

NOTE: If the RDB$OWNER_NAME is not a valid regular identifier (starts with A-Z, rest is A-Z,0-9 or _ or $), you will need to identify users with the RDB$ADMIN privilege:

```sql
select RDB$USER from RDB$USER_PRIVILEGES where RDB$RELATION_NAME = 'RDB$ADMIN' and RDB$OBJECT_TYPE = 13;
```

As a last resort, try to identify the database owner:

```sql
select distinct RDB$OWNER_NAME as DATABASE_OWNER
from RDB$RELATIONS
where RDB$SYSTEM_FLAG = 1;
```

Now, create a new user with the owner name of the role or one of the users with the RDB$ADMIN privilege using the steps described in *"Creating a new user"* (in the following steps, I use the username BROKEN_LOCK).

If the user already exists, change their password with:

```sql
alter user BROKEN_LOCK set password 'thepassword';
```

#### Drop the SYSDBA role

Access the database with ISQL and the user that owns the role (or is an admin) as found in the previous step:

```bash
isql -user broken_lock -password thepassword -role RDB$ADMIN localhost:thedatabase
```

The option `-role RDB$ADMIN` is only needed for the users with the RDB$ADMIN privilege, but is silently ignored for users that don't have that role.

Inside ISQL, drop the role:

```sql
drop role SYSDBA;
commit;
exit;
```

You should now be able access the database with SYSDBA.

---

(*): If you don't have any other databases on your system, you will need to create one first (or use the GSEC route).

Start ISQL:

```bash
isql
```

And in ISQL (substitute C:\Databases\mydatabase.fdb with a valid path, and masterkey with the actual password):

```sql
create database 'C:\Databases\mydatabase.fdb' user 'sysdba' password 'masterkey';
```

Then use the database path instead of `employee` to create the users.

Comment: I ran `select RDB$OWNER_NAME from RDB$ROLES where RDB$ROLE_NAME = 'SYSDBA';` and it returned me [COLOREXPERT](https://i.ibb.co/LnrFnBg/image.png) as the value. But from this point on im not sure what is the next step, Is it to alter the password ? but i get an error. Have a look at [what i did](https://i.ibb.co/4Z2yJBs/image.png)

Comment: As I mentioned: _"Create a new user with the owner name of the role or one of the users with the RDB$ADMIN privilege using above steps"_, so follow use either point 1 or point 2 to create a new user, just like you did when you created user `thenewuser`. The suggestion to alter the user was only if the user already exists on your system (which it doesn't judging by the error).

Comment: I see so while in the "protected" database ill have to create a user named COLOREXPERT (the owner of SYSDBA). It threw an [error](https://i.ibb.co/tJdSqHQ/image.png) `no permission for insert/write access to TABLE USERS`. I even tried signing in  as role admin.

Comment: But if you mean that i go back to the employee database and create the user there, ill try this out

Comment: Yes, that is what I mean. Users are not *per database*, and the user `thenewuser` cannot create users (it is not an admin), so you have to use SYSDBA on employee (or another database were SYSDBA can connect).

Comment: Got it ! I now can access the database with SYSDBA yey! Thank you so much sir mark